# Use markov analysis to Calculate probabilities of being in all possible states and the final probability of system success and failure

Tags: probability

The overall system has 3 systems: power supply, subsystem 1, and subsystem 2. Subsystem 1 is two devices in parallel and subsystem 2 is two devices in series. The individual probability of devices in failed states are: power supply 0.005, device 1a 0.25, 1b 0.25, 2a 0.025, 2b 0.025.

[image: current work completed]

Comment: Welcome to CV. If this question relates to a class exercise, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the tag to modify the question accordingly.